# IOException was unhandled error

Tags: c#, file-io

I have the following code, and I'm getting an `IOException` error. It says it is in use by a different process. I do not have the file opened somewhere, the application creates the file.

This is my code:

In function one:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter data = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\temp.txt");
data.WriteLine(temp);
data.Close()
```

after this, a second function is called which should process the temp file. The lines which do something with the IO are these:

```
string[] part = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp.txt");
```

in this function the `string[] part` is modified and added to a final complete file:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(Datas.Core.outputDir + @"\" + Datas.Core.outputName + ".txt", part);
```

I guess the `System.IO.ReadAllLines` function keeps the file busy, how can I change my code so I can access the file again?

Comment: You need to call `data.Dispose()`

Comment: Your code as posted cannot keep the file locked.  Somewhere in the real program you are forgetting to close/dispose or are swallowing an exception without using the *using* statement.  Like you did in the first snippet.

Comment: @dbaseman can you repeat your comment as answer, so i can mark it as answer? this solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`data.Dispose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) (not just `Close`) in order to completely release the file handle.

Answer (score 2):

The method `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` will not keep the file busy, it will open the file for reading then close it again automatically upon finished. The problem might be in the following line

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(Datas.Core.outputDir + @"\" + Datas.Core.outputName + ".txt", part);
```

I believe that it is better to use the class `StreamWriter` to append or write text to a specific file and control the writer (class) later.

Here's a sample code

```
string Path = @"C:\temp.txt"; // You can change this to anything you would like
StreamWriter _TextWriter = new StreamWriter(Path, true); // change to "false" if you do not want to append
```

Then you can use one of the following to:

**!**  Append text to the last line

```
_TextWriter.Write("something");
```

**!** Create a new line at the end of the file then append text to the last line

```
_TextWriter.WriteLine("something");
```

Then close the `StreamWriter` using the following code when you finish processing the file

```
_TextWriter.Close();
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the `System.IO.StreamWriter` in a using statement so that it will get disposed properly:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter data = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\temp.txt"))
{
    data.WriteLine(temp);
}
```

This is how the [example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx) is presented.